# How to store string or integer in java.swing JTextField?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, input

Hello I am working on this project to store student names and record their grades. I have the entire program mapped out and all I need to do now is record the integers and strings from the user input and call it from different classes. I am having trouble with this. Do I use an array? How do I call from another class? Thank you.

```
    package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Student extends JFrame {
    private JFrame studentFrame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField studentNameTextField;
    protected Component frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Student frame = new Student();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Student() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLabel = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLabel.setBounds(189, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLabel);

        JLabel lblPleaseEnterThe = new JLabel("Please enter the student name");
        lblPleaseEnterThe.setBounds(130, 105, 194, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblPleaseEnterThe);

        studentNameTextField = new JTextField("Enter here");
        String stdname = studentNameTextField.getText();
        studentNameTextField.setBounds(130, 133, 194, 26);
        contentPane.add(studentNameTextField);
        studentNameTextField.setColumns(10);

        JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                if(continueButton.isEnabled()){
                Student.this.dispose();
                    Student studentScreen = new Student();
                    studentScreen.dispose();

                    AddGrades addGradesScreen = new AddGrades();
                    addGradesScreen.setVisible(true);


                }
            }
        });
        continueButton.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(continueButton);

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {


                if(cancelButton.isEnabled()){




                    MainScreen mainScreenScreen = new MainScreen();
                    mainScreenScreen.setVisible(true);
                    contentPane.setVisible(false);
                    contentPane.disable();


                }
            }
        });


        cancelButton.setBounds(207, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(cancelButton);
    }

    private void initizalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Is it something along the lines of this?

```
studentNameTextField = new JTextField("Enter here");
        String stdname = studentNameTextField.getText();
```

I know this would be storing it but how do I call that in a different class so I can make it appear on a different Frame?

Update: Okay so I've done this

```
Student frame = new Student();
        String stdname = frame.studentNameTextField.getText();
        JLabel addgradesLabel = new JLabel("Add grades for" + frame.studentNameTextField);
        addgradesLabel.setBounds(139, 34, 167, 29);
        contentPane.add(addgradesLabel);
```

And it's still not working. I believe I'm not implementing this correctly. I'm trying to title the label with what the user inputs for the name. So it would but "Add grades for" + stdname But it's not calling it correctly. How can I fix this?

Here is my code from the AddStudentName class

```
studentNameTextField = new JTextField();
        studentNameTextField.setBounds(130, 133, 194, 26);
        contentPane.add(studentNameTextField);
        studentNameTextField.setColumns(10);

        JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                if(continueButton.isEnabled()){
                Student.this.dispose();
                    Student studentScreen = new Student();
                    studentScreen.dispose();


                    AddGrades addGradesScreen = new AddGrades();
                    addGradesScreen.setVisible(true);




                }
            }
        });
```

What should I add here to save the input that the user is inputting into the JTextField? Thanks for the help

Here's the full code for the classes:

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Student extends JFrame {
    private JFrame studentFrame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public JTextField studentNameTextField;
    protected Component frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Student frame = new Student();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Student() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLabel = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLabel.setBounds(189, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLabel);

        JLabel lblPleaseEnterThe = new JLabel("Please enter the student name");
        lblPleaseEnterThe.setBounds(130, 105, 194, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblPleaseEnterThe);


        JTextField studentNameTextField = new JTextField();

        studentNameTextField.setBounds(130, 133, 194, 26);
        contentPane.add(studentNameTextField);
        studentNameTextField.setColumns(10);

        JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                if(continueButton.isEnabled()){

                    Student studentScreen = new Student();
                    studentScreen.dispose();

                    AddGrades addGradesScreen = new AddGrades();
                    addGradesScreen.setVisible(true);



                }
            }
        });


        continueButton.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(continueButton);

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {


                if(cancelButton.isEnabled()){




                    MainScreen mainScreenScreen = new MainScreen();
                    mainScreenScreen.setVisible(true);
                    contentPane.setVisible(false);
                    contentPane.disable();


                }
            }
        });


        cancelButton.setBounds(207, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(cancelButton);
    }

    private void initizalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and:

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AddGrades extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField Assignment1;
    private JTextField Assignment2;
    private JTextField Assignment3;
    private JTextField Assignment4;
    private JLabel testsLabel;
    private JTextField Test1;
    private JTextField Test2;
    public JTextField Test3;
    public JTextField Test4;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public JFrame frame;
    public JButton continueButton;
    public JButton exitButton;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddGrades frame = new AddGrades();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AddGrades frame = new AddGrades();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AddGrades() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLabel = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLabel.setBounds(189, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLabel);


        JLabel addgradesLabel = new JLabel("Add grades for" + stdname);
        addgradesLabel.setBounds(139, 34, 167, 29);
        contentPane.add(addgradesLabel);

        JLabel assignmentsLabel = new JLabel("Assignments:");
        assignmentsLabel.setBounds(19, 75, 86, 16);
        contentPane.add(assignmentsLabel);

        Assignment1 = new JTextField();
        Assignment1.setBounds(54, 91, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Assignment1);
        Assignment1.setColumns(10);

        Assignment2 = new JTextField();
        Assignment2.setBounds(54, 129, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Assignment2);
        Assignment2.setColumns(10);

        Assignment3 = new JTextField();
        Assignment3.setBounds(54, 167, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Assignment3);
        Assignment3.setColumns(10);

        Assignment4 = new JTextField();
        Assignment4.setBounds(54, 205, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Assignment4);
        Assignment4.setColumns(10);

        testsLabel = new JLabel("Tests:");
        testsLabel.setBounds(243, 75, 38, 16);
        contentPane.add(testsLabel);

        Test1 = new JTextField();
        Test1.setBounds(262, 91, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Test1);
        Test1.setColumns(10);

        Test2 = new JTextField();
        Test2.setBounds(262, 129, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Test2);
        Test2.setColumns(10);

        Test3 = new JTextField();
        Test3.setBounds(262, 167, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Test3);
        Test3.setColumns(10);

        Test4 = new JTextField();
        Test4.setBounds(262, 205, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(Test4);
        Test4.setColumns(10);

        continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
                if (continueButton.isEnabled()){

                    MainScreen mainScreenScreen = new MainScreen();
                    mainScreenScreen.setVisible(true);

                }


            }
        });
        continueButton.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(continueButton);

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        exitButton.setBounds(208, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(exitButton);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to take the input from the JTextField

```
JTextField studentNameTextField = new JTextField();
```

and set it on the label

```
JLabel addgradesLabel = new JLabel("Add grades for" + stdname);
```

Where stdname would be the user input from the JTextField.

Now I'm getting errors from

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddGrades frame = new AddGrades();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AddGrades frame = new AddGrades();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

AddGrades frame = new AddGrades(); gives me error Add argument to match AddGrades(String)

The constructor AddGrades() is undefined

Comment: How do you call what from another class? Clarify your question. It seems, at first look, that you need to study a little about Java and OOP in general.

Comment: Should be answered now - see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The best way to do this is to pass an argument to your newly created AddGrades class. See below:

```
public AddGrades(String stdname) {
    JLabel addgradesLabel = new JLabel("Add grades for " + stdname);
}
```

You will need to modify your code to pass a string to your AddGrades class wherever you create it:

```
JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if(continueButton.isEnabled()){

            Student studentScreen = new Student();
            studentScreen.dispose();

            AddGrades addGradesScreen = new AddGrades(studentNameTextField.getText());
            addGradesScreen.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
});
```

That worked for me - I downloaded your code and tested it.

Comment: I've tried this but I believe I'm not implementing this correctly. I've updated my original post with some more code. Thanks

Comment: @Adam Based on your code, it looks like you don't give the user time to enter anything - the Student frame is displayed, then immediately, a new label is made. When that happens, the user hasn't entered text yet. The fix for this is to use action listeners. I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm still having trouble implementing your suggestions. I'm going to provide the full code for these two classes for you, if you don't mind could you take a look?

Comment: @Adam Happy to. So when the user enters a name and clicks continue, you want the new menu to be populated with the user's name right?

Comment: Yes! I want to take what the user enters in the JTextField and put it in the JLabel. And in the future I want to enter and save their grades too. Is there a simple way I can do all of this?

Comment: I'm getting errors for AddGrades frame = new AddGrades(); under public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @Adam right - like I said, you will need to change your AddGrades() constructor to take a String. So pass it a String and it will be fine.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out and it's working. Will this also store the name? I need  to be able to pull back up the name later and view the grades from a different class.

Comment: I'm going to put this JTextField entry into a JComboBox, so the user can select which students grades they want to view

Answer (score 0):

`JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` would be my first thought, but if you can't do that then you could use [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) to parse a `String` to `int` and a [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to format the numbers to `String`s

Maybe have a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for starters

> I know this would be storing it but how do I call that in a different class so I can make it appear on a different JFrame?

That's a open question with little context.  You might use some kind of "model" which represented one or more `Student` values; you might use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to allow the editor to generate events to interested parties which would tell them that something has changed; you might use a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller); you might use a modal dialog and when it's closed, ask the editor for the values via getters.

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

One of things you want to keep in mind is "responsibility" and "encapsulation". You don't want outside parties to have uncontrolled access into your editor or model, this could allow them to modify the state in an uncontrolled way leading to inconsistencies in your data or UI.

You need to decide who is actually responsible for modifying the state of the model. There's no "right" answer, for example, you could have the editor either be capable of editing existing student objects or creating new ones based on how it's configured, equally, you could also have the editor be "dumb" and simply use setters to setup the editor and getters to get the values.

There are lots of options available to you, which you would use would be based on the context in which you want to use it. My gut feeling is start with an observer pattern and a modal dialog.

Comment: I really respect you and you are a boss at answering questions, so no disrespect, but I don't think this answer is right. His question is centered around how to access the value in his text field from another class, and this doesn't address that.

Comment: @nhouser9 Yep, the title and the question don't match :P. Check the update, also, way to blow away encapsulation by the way ;)